# Stop piped programs from exchanging outdated information

Tags: python, bash, pipe

I have two piped programs: a debug log which updates very quickly which sends the information to a python program which processes the information:

```
./debugClient | python processor.py
```

The problem is, the debugClient program produces output real-time and the processor program needs to be able to process at real-time as well. It is entirely okay and expected that some information is missed as long as the program occurs real-time. However when the two are piped together I seem to only get old debug information going to processor.py. I understand why this might be the case as the two programs are supposed to run concurrently and the program involves more than just a STDIN loop. But I am confused on the buffer involved and why the new information isn't being sent instead of the old info.

Comment: Can you paste please the content of both modules?

Comment: There is absolutely no possibility of information being "missed" with a pipeline - anything that the left side writes, WILL be read by the right side, no matter how long it takes for that program to get around to it.  If you want to drop data that's coming in faster than it can be processed, you'd have to implement that yourself - perhaps the processor could read the pipe continuously (in a thread, perhaps?), keeping only the most recent item for the main program to operate on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accomplished what I wanted to by creating two threads, one that only collected the information and one that processed it.